# Visual Studio 2010: How do I create custom Code Analysis rules?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

How do I create custom Code Analysis rules?

Comment: I typed your title into google...

Comment: So did I. First result: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380660.aspx

Comment: Why did you post a link that has nothing to do with creating custom rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Microsoft All-In-One Code Framework:

- [VBCustomCodeAnalysisRule](http://1code.codeplex.com/releases/view/62253#DownloadId=215121)
- [CSCustomCodeAnalysisRule](http://1code.codeplex.com/releases/view/62253#DownloadId=215047)

Ref: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/83cf00fd-9b7c-48d8-9df5-85881562dd00